# After adding selenium lib jar files, eclipse does not show any output and javaw.exe crash is shown in event log

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

After adding selenium lib jar files to project, **Eclipse** does not show any output and **javaw.exe** crash is shown in event log of windows10, as below:

> Faulting application name: javaw.exe, version: 8.0.1210.13, time
>   stamp: 0x584f5d7e Faulting module name: nvinitx.dll, version:
>   21.21.13.7849, time stamp: 0x58820bbf Exception code: 0xc0000409 Fault offset: 0x000000000000d150 Faulting process id: 0x2cb0 Faulting
>   application start time: 0x01d27d37213f3e01 Faulting application path:
>   C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin\javaw.exe Faulting module path:
>   C:\WINDOWS\system32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nvdmi.inf_amd64_fd06216336fcf4a2\nvinitx.dll
>   Report Id: a7c0f002-a7d6-4cb4-ac5c-235447de4da7 Faulting package full
>   name:  Faulting package-relative application ID:*

If I remove selenium jar files from project, `system.out.println("test")` works fine and "test" is printed on console. As soon as I add selenium jar files, it does not work. Tried re-installing JDK and eclipse multiple times.

Using selenium-java-3.0.1, JDK 1.8.0_121 and eclipse neon.2 and TestNG.

Tried with selenium-java-3.0.0 but no use.

Here is the simple code I am trying to run:

```
package p;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;

public class NewTest {
  @Test
  public void f() {
      System.out.println("testng");
  }
  @BeforeMethod
  public void beforeMethod() {
  }

  @AfterMethod
  public void afterMethod() {
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using Selenium standalone library file.